# Passing hidden value to controller (asp.netmvc)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Trying to pass a value with Ajax.Beginform but not working for some reason.

What I’m doing:

1. I’m making an ajax call which returns an id and replaces a hidden element.

   `Ajax: Ajax.BeginForm("Action1",      "Controller1", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode

    = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "pageId" })`

Hidden Element (which is outside of the above `Ajax.BeginForm`):

```
 <input type="hidden" name="pageId" id="pageId" value=""/>
```

2. Now, I want to use that pageId (in the hidden value) and pass it to another action, using another Ajax.BeginForm.

   `Ajax.BeginForm("Action2", "Controller1”))
               {
                   <input type="hidden" name="pageId" id="pageId" value=""/>
                   <input type="submit" />
               }`
3. The controller Action2 looks like this:

   ```
        public void Action2(string pageId)
        {

        }
   ```

   But this is not working obviously. What are your suggestions?

Comment: Are you passing any value to your input? As i can see now it's empty.

Comment: Well, the first Ajax call (1) is returning a string and by using the insertion replace I thought I was setting a value to the hidden field. The hidden field in developer tool looks has got the pageId value set to the element.

Comment: Show code pease that changes value please

Comment: No 1 is the Ajax vall which changes the value. The call is returning a string and replacing an existens element with that string. The element in Dev tools then looks like this: <input type="hidden" name="pageId" id ="pageId" value>123</input> where 123 is representing the pageId that is returned.

Comment: That is not valid HTML.  You need to set the value attribute.  Hidden inputs cannot have inner content like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that i understand your problem what you are facing. Please correct me if i am wrong.

**First Ajax call which will set your pageid**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Foo", "FooController", new AjaxOptions    {

    HttpMethod = "Post",
    OnSuccess = "success"
}))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnsubmit" />
}


    [HttpPost]   // you said you return a string here
    public string  Foo()
    {
        return "1";
    }

<script type="text/javascript">
function success(result) { 
    $('#pageId').val(result);
}
</script>
```

**secondly here is the place where your pageid will be set**. when you will press the submit button below the set value will be posted to the controller.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Foo1", "FooController", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "HandlePostback" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="pageId" id="pageId" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnsubmit" />
}


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Foo1(int pageId)
    {
        return View();
    }
```